# Why does increasing the number of rounds for CCKeyDerivationPBKDF improve security?

Tags: ios, security, aes

Having read Rob Napier's blog post on [Properly Encrypting with CommonCrypto](http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564) I'm still having trouble understanding *why* increasing the number of hashing iterations makes an attacker "waste some time".

The man page for [CCKeyDerivationPBKDF](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/CCKeyDerivationPBKDF.3cc.html) describes rounds as:

> The number of rounds of the Pseudo Random Algorithm to use.

Is the principle here that the attacker is attempting to break the password by going through a series of guesses but in order to turn the password into the key to see if it works they themselves have to iterate number-of-rounds times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the attacker also has to do the same number of rounds increasing his work and time.

Comment: This is because the attacker is trying likely passwords, yes? If the attacker were just brute forcing through every possible key (theoretically) this wouldn't make a difference, yes?

Comment: A brute force attack, key by key is impractical these days with the current key lengths. Thus password attacks are the best method. Further there are lists of known key vs usage as a starting point. Also information about the target such as the contents of their computer will also yield good attack material.

Answer (score 3):

That's one principle. Another benefit is that differing numbers of rounds among potential targets makes a one-size-fits-all attack harder to work. Much like salts, diversity and added work in crypto makes attackers have to mount expensive attacks on each target. Such obstacles might deter an attacker from hitting your site: he or she notices there are much easier sites to target and moves on.

If your site is important, the reality of the situation is that the attackers usually work around crypto rather than bore through it. Bruce Schneier points out crypto is usually the strongest link. They're more likely to own your box or exploit a flaw in their web app. Once they have control, they can intercept or manipulate whatever data they want. So, it's best to just use best practice configuration for crypto and then apply most of your energy to looking for issues at application layer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is right.   As hardware becomes faster over time, it becomes cheaper and easier to compute key values for huge numbers potential inputs.   Increasing the number of iterations that need to be performed allows the cost of computing the key to increase over time as hardware gets better without having to switch to entirely new, more expensive algorithms.

Comment: The answer seems to imply that the number of rounds will increase as computers get faster. This also assumes that the attacker gets to choose the hardware (computer) making the attack. But if the target's device must be used, such as a smart-card, TPM or TPM equivalent, the device may guarantee a maximum tries/unit time removing the need of increasing the number of rounds. I am aware of decryption devices that guarantee this.